# JQuery - Multiply 3 input fields and auto populate the 4th input

Tags: jquery

I've got 3 input fields:

```
<input type="text" name="height" /> * <input type="text" name="width" /> *<input type="text" name="length" />
and the total:
= <input type="text" name="total" />
```

how to do with jQuery that will auto populate the total field?

Thanks!

Comment: You Should write logic on onblur or onfocusout function of any input field.Check answer by @Sebastian

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/xZ3LM/ check my answer demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should add id to your inputs:

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" ... /> 
// also for 2, 3 and 4 ...
```

Then, you can simply add this jquery event to dynamically calculate the result:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        $("#txt1, #txt2, #txt3").change(function() {
            $("#txt4").val($("#txt1").val() * $("#txt2").val() * $("#txt3").val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/uGgfh/

```
$('.num').change(function(){
    var tot = 1;
    $.each($('input[class=num]'),function(){
      var curr_val = $(this).val();
        if(curr_val != ""){
          tot = tot * curr_val;
          $('.tot').val(tot);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

add id to the all input's, then `$('input#input4').val($('input#input1').val()*$('input#input2').val()*$('input#input3').val())`

Comment: you can change id to you'r name from the input lik id="height", id="width".... then change input1, input2... to this id's

Comment: Thanks for this, but it doesn't auto populate the total field.

Comment: use 
if($('input#input1').val()!="" && $('input#input2').val()!=""...)
{
$('input#input4').val($('input#input1').val()*$('input#input2').val()*$('input#input3').val())
}

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/xZ3LM/)

```
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function () {
    var result = 1;
    var x=0;
    $('input[type="text"]').not('input[type="text"][name=total]').each(function () {
        if (this.value != '') {
            result *= this.value ;
            x++;
        }
    });
    $('input[type="text"][name=total]').val((x == 0) ?0:result);
});
```