# jquery- calculate a total value after filling out a checkbox/radio/dropdown form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, jquery-selectors

I have a payment form with three sections. Basically, the first is a "radio" list with multipliers, the second is a "checkbox" list with set values, and the third is a dropdown list with multipliers as well ==> [(jsfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/gx9zL995/). For clarity, I inserted a text box that would display the total calculated value.

When users fill out this form, how do I calculate and display the total?

I tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18224543/jquery-multiply-3-input-fields-and-auto-populate-the-4th-input) stack overflow response, but it does not work at all.

```
$('input').change(function(){
    var tot = 1;
    $.each($('input'),function(){
      var curr_val = $(this).val();
        if(curr_val != ""){
          tot = tot * curr_val;
          $('#total').val(tot);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What do you want to do, you want multiply selected value or all the values??

Comment: All the values. So if a user selects "x2", selects 3 checkboxes (each have a value of 4), and selects "3 weeks" for example, the total would display 504 (2x3x4x21)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your selector to *exclude* the `#total` as you don't want to listen to its change - `$(':input').not('#total').change`.

You can use a [`#map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) jquery function to get the array of *checked* boxes.

The next step would be to *multiply* them all - using [`#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function to add the array.

See demo below:

```js
$(':input').not('#total').change(function() {
  var tot = 1;

  var s1 = +$('input[name=section1]:checked').val();
  var s2 = $('input[name=section2]:checked').map(function() {
    return +$(this).val();
  }).get();
  var s3 = +$('select').val();
  $('#total').val(s1 * (s2.reduce(function(p,c){
    return p + c;
  },0) || 1) * s3);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="">
  <div id="section1">Section 1
    <br><input type="radio" name="section1" value="2"> x2
    <br><input type="radio" name="section1" value="1.5"> x1.5
    <br><input type="radio" name="section1" value="1.5"> x1.5
    <br><input type="radio" name="section1" value="1.5"> x1.5
    <br><input type="radio" name="section1" value="1"> x1
    <br><input type="radio" name="section1" value="1"> x1
  </div>
  <br>
  <div id="section2">Section 2
    <br><label><input type="checkbox" name="section2" value="4"><span>1</span></label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="section2" value="4"><span>2</span></label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="section2" value="4"><span>3</span></label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="section2" value="4"><span>4</span></label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="section2" value="4"><span>5</span></label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="section2" value="4"><span>6</span></label>
    <br><label><input type="checkbox" name="section2" value="4"><span>7</span></label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="section2" value="4"><span>8</span></label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="section2" value="4"><span>9</span></label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="section2" value="4"><span>10</span></label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="section2" value="4"><span>11</span></label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="section2" value="4"><span>12</span></label>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>Section 3<br>
    <select>
   <option value="7">1 week</option>
   <option value="14">2 weeks</option>
   <option value="21">3 weeks</option>
   <option value="28">4 weeks</option>
  </select>
  </div>
  <input type="text" value="0" id="total">
</form>
```

Comment: This works but I just realized a fault in my question pertaining to section 2. In Section 2, every checkbox has a value of 4, but selecting more checkboxes should add 4 not of multiply. Selecting "x2" in section 1, selecting one checkbox in section 2, and selecting "1 week" in section 3 equals 56 (2 x 4 x 7), but selecting two checkboxes gives me 224 (because it's doing 2 x 4 x 4 x7), when in fact I want 112 (2 x (4+4) x 7); selecting 3 checkboxes should give me 163, selecting 4 checkboxes should give me 224, etc.,

Comment: @Cris oops, missed `checked` selector for the section1, seems ok now? :)