# complicated calculation based on categories selection on JS or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an excel like table as[The image version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tpuv.png), I will need to do real time calculation on HTML using JS or JQuery. 
Below example do the calculation based on single value as you can see mine changes and I have two drop-down 10 selection other one with 16 selection.

Calculation rules are:
If user selects **Origin Europe** and select **Volume** 10, then for the matching 10 number fields I will need calculate amount x **Volume** 10 corresponding value from below the table

Apple  = User input **3** and corresponding value from table is **0**  so my result will be **0**.

Boysenberry  = User input **233** and corresponding value from table is **1**  so my result will be **233**.

so on, I have 10 tables for lookup for corresponding calculation value it changes based on the **Origin** Drop-down and **Volume**.
If I had one it was easy when I have more table I bit straggle I think there are some good way to do the calculation. 
***Thanks for your help in advance.***

[jquery- calculate a total value after filling out a checkbox/radio/dropdown form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45911413/jquery-calculate-a-total-value-after-filling-out-a-checkbox-radio-dropdown-form)

```html
<div>
   <label class="description" for="element_2">Product Origin</label>
   <select class="element select medium" id="element_2" name="element_2">
      <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
      <option value="1" >Europe</option>
      <option value="2" >Asia</option>
      <option value="3" >China</option>
      <option value="3" >India</option>
      <option value="3" >USA</option>
      <option value="3" >Africa</option>
   </select>
</div>
<div>
   <label class="description" for="element_1">Volume</label>
   <select class="element select medium" id="element_1" name="element_1">
      <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
      <option value="10" >10</option>
      <option value="100" >100</option>
      <option value="1000" >1000</option>
      <option value="2000" >2000</option>
      <option value="3000" >3000</option>
      <option value="4000" >4000</option>
      <option value="5000" >5000</option>
      <option value="6000" >6000</option>
      <option value="6000" >6000</option>
      <option value="8000" >8000</option>
      <option value="9000" >9000</option>
      <option value="10000" >10000</option>
      <option value="20000" >20000</option>
      <option value="30000" >30000</option>
      <option value="40000" >40000</option>
      <option value="50000" >50000</option>
   </select>
</div>
<div>
   <label class="description" for="element_1">Apple </label>
   <input id="element_1" name="element_1" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
</div>
<div>
   <label class="description" for="element_2">Apricot </label>
   <input id="element_2" name="element_2" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
</div>
<div>
   <label class="description" for="element_3">Banana </label>
   <input id="element_3" name="element_3" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
</div>
<div>
   <label class="description" for="element_4">Bilberry </label>
   <input id="element_4" name="element_4" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
</div>
<div>
   <label class="description" for="element_5">Blackberry </label>
   <input id="element_5" name="element_5" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
</div>
<div>
   <label class="description" for="element_6">Blackcurrant </label>
   <input id="element_6" name="element_6" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
</div>
<div>
   <label class="description" for="element_7">Blueberry </label>
   <input id="element_7" name="element_7" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
</div>
<div>  
   <label class="description" for="element_8">Boysenberry </label>
   <input id="element_8" name="element_8" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
</div>
<div>
   <label class="description" for="element_9">Cherry </label>
   <input id="element_9" name="element_9" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
</div>
<div>
   <label class="description" for="element_10">Coconut </label>
   <input id="element_10" name="element_10" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
</div>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th title="Field #1"><strong>Category 1: Origin Europe</strong></th>
         <th title="Field #2"><strong>10</strong></th>
         <th title="Field #3"><strong>100</strong></th>
         <th title="Field #4"><strong>1000</strong></th>
         <th title="Field #5"><strong>2000</strong></th>
         <th title="Field #6"><strong>3000</strong></th>
         <th title="Field #7"><strong>4000</strong></th>
         <th title="Field #8"><strong>5000</strong></th>
         <th title="Field #9"><strong>6000</strong></th>
         <th title="Field #10"><strong>7000</strong></th>
         <th title="Field #11"><strong>8000</strong></th>
         <th title="Field #12"><strong>9000</strong></th>
         <th title="Field #13"><strong>1000</strong></th>
         <th title="Field #14"><strong>10000</strong></th>
         <th title="Field #15"><strong>20000</strong></th>
         <th title="Field #16"><strong>30000</strong></th>
         <th title="Field #17"><strong>40000</strong></th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Apple</td>
         <td align="right">0.1</td>
         <td align="right">0.5</td>
         <td align="right">1</td>
         <td align="right">2</td>
         <td align="right">3</td>
         <td align="right">4</td>
         <td align="right">5</td>
         <td align="right">6</td>
         <td align="right">7</td>
         <td align="right">8</td>
         <td align="right">9</td>
         <td align="right">10</td>
         <td align="right">11</td>
         <td align="right">12</td>
         <td align="right">13</td>
         <td align="right">14</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Apricot</td>
         <td align="right">0</td>
         <td align="right">0</td>
         <td align="right">0</td>
         <td align="right">0.5</td>
         <td align="right">1</td>
         <td align="right">1.5</td>
         <td align="right">2</td>
         <td align="right">2.5</td>
         <td align="right">3</td>
         <td align="right">3.5</td>
         <td align="right">4</td>
         <td align="right">4.5</td>
         <td align="right">5</td>
         <td align="right">5.5</td>
         <td align="right">6</td>
         <td align="right">7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Banana</td>
         <td align="right">0.1</td>
         <td align="right">0.5</td>
         <td align="right">1</td>
         <td align="right">2</td>
         <td align="right">4</td>
         <td align="right">5</td>
         <td align="right">6</td>
         <td align="right">7</td>
         <td align="right">8</td>
         <td align="right">9</td>
         <td align="right">10</td>
         <td align="right">12</td>
         <td align="right">14</td>
         <td align="right">16</td>
         <td align="right">18</td>
         <td align="right">20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Bilberry</td>
         <td align="right">1</td>
         <td align="right">5</td>
         <td align="right">10</td>
         <td align="right">10</td>
         <td align="right">15</td>
         <td align="right">20</td>
         <td align="right">25</td>
         <td align="right">30</td>
         <td align="right">35</td>
         <td align="right">40</td>
         <td align="right">45</td>
         <td align="right">50</td>
         <td align="right">55</td>
         <td align="right">60</td>
         <td align="right">65</td>
         <td align="right">70</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Blackberry</td>
         <td align="right">0.1</td>
         <td align="right">5</td>
         <td align="right">10</td>
         <td align="right">20</td>
         <td align="right">50</td>
         <td align="right">75</td>
         <td align="right">100</td>
         <td align="right">125</td>
         <td align="right">150</td>
         <td align="right">175</td>
         <td align="right">200</td>
         <td align="right">225</td>
         <td align="right">250</td>
         <td align="right">275</td>
         <td align="right">300</td>
         <td align="right">350</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Blackcurrant</td>
         <td align="right">0.1</td>
         <td align="right">0.5</td>
         <td align="right">1</td>
         <td align="right">2</td>
         <td align="right">2</td>
         <td align="right">4</td>
         <td align="right">4</td>
         <td align="right">4</td>
         <td align="right">6</td>
         <td align="right">6</td>
         <td align="right">6</td>
         <td align="right">8</td>
         <td align="right">8</td>
         <td align="right">10</td>
         <td align="right">12</td>
         <td align="right">14</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Blueberry</td>
         <td align="right">0.1</td>
         <td align="right">0.5</td>
         <td align="right">1</td>
         <td align="right">4</td>
         <td align="right">6</td>
         <td align="right">8</td>
         <td align="right">10</td>
         <td align="right">12</td>
         <td align="right">14</td>
         <td align="right">16</td>
         <td align="right">18</td>
         <td align="right">20</td>
         <td align="right">24</td>
         <td align="right">28</td>
         <td align="right">30</td>
         <td align="right">36</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Boysenberry</td>
         <td align="right">0.5</td>
         <td align="right">1</td>
         <td align="right">2.5</td>
         <td align="right">4</td>
         <td align="right">5.5</td>
         <td align="right">7</td>
         <td align="right">8.5</td>
         <td align="right">10</td>
         <td align="right">11.5</td>
         <td align="right">13</td>
         <td align="right">14.5</td>
         <td align="right">16</td>
         <td align="right">17.5</td>
         <td align="right">19</td>
         <td align="right">20.5</td>
         <td align="right">22</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Cherry</td>
         <td align="right">0.5</td>
         <td align="right">1</td>
         <td align="right">2.5</td>
         <td align="right">5</td>
         <td align="right">8</td>
         <td align="right">10</td>
         <td align="right">15</td>
         <td align="right">20</td>
         <td align="right">25</td>
         <td align="right">28</td>
         <td align="right">31</td>
         <td align="right">35</td>
         <td align="right">40</td>
         <td align="right">45</td>
         <td align="right">50</td>
         <td align="right">55</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Coconut</td>
         <td align="right">0.1</td>
         <td align="right">0.25</td>
         <td align="right">0.5</td>
         <td align="right">0.5</td>
         <td align="right">1</td>
         <td align="right">1</td>
         <td align="right">2</td>
         <td align="right">2</td>
         <td align="right">2</td>
         <td align="right">2</td>
         <td align="right">2.5</td>
         <td align="right">2.5</td>
         <td align="right">3</td>
         <td align="right">3</td>
         <td align="right">3</td>
         <td align="right">3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         </br>
         </br>
         <td><strong>Category 2 Origin Asia</strong></td>
         <td align="right"><strong>10</strong></td>
         <td align="right"><strong>100</strong></td>
         <td align="right"><strong>1000</strong></td>
         <td align="right"><strong>2000</strong></td>
         <td align="right"><strong>3000</strong></td>
         <td align="right"><strong>4000</strong></td>
         <td align="right"><strong>5000</strong></td>
         <td align="right"><strong>6000</strong></td>
         <td align="right"><strong>7000</strong></td>
         <td align="right"><strong>8000</strong></td>
         <td align="right"><strong>9000</strong></td>
         <td align="right"><strong>1000</strong></td>
         <td align="right"><strong>10000</strong></td>
         <td align="right"><strong>20000</strong></td>
         <td align="right"><strong>30000</strong></td>
         <td align="right"><strong>40000</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Apple</td>
         <td align="right">0.1</td>
         <td align="right">0.5</td>
         <td align="right">1</td>
         <td align="right">5</td>
         <td align="right">10</td>
         <td align="right">15</td>
         <td align="right">17.7</td>
         <td align="right">21.5</td>
         <td align="right">25.3</td>
         <td align="right">29.1</td>
         <td align="right">32.9</td>
         <td align="right">36.7</td>
         <td align="right">40.5</td>
         <td align="right">44.3</td>
         <td align="right">48.1</td>
         <td align="right">51.9</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Apricot</td>
         <td align="right">0</td>
         <td align="right">0</td>
         <td align="right">0</td>
         <td align="right">0.5</td>
         <td align="right">1</td>
         <td align="right">1.5</td>
         <td align="right">2</td>
         <td align="right">2.5</td>
         <td align="right">3</td>
         <td align="right">3.5</td>
         <td align="right">4</td>
         <td align="right">4.5</td>
         <td align="right">5</td>
         <td align="right">5.5</td>
         <td align="right">6</td>
         <td align="right">7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Banana</td>
         <td align="right">0.1</td>
         <td align="right">0.5</td>
         <td align="right">1</td>
         <td align="right">5</td>
         <td align="right">10</td>
         <td align="right">15</td>
         <td align="right">20</td>
         <td align="right">25</td>
         <td align="right">27</td>
         <td align="right">30</td>
         <td align="right">33</td>
         <td align="right">36</td>
         <td align="right">40</td>
         <td align="right">45</td>
         <td align="right">50</td>
         <td align="right">55</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Bilberry</td>
         <td align="right">1</td>
         <td align="right">5</td>
         <td align="right">10</td>
         <td align="right">15</td>
         <td align="right">20</td>
         <td align="right">25</td>
         <td align="right">30</td>
         <td align="right">35</td>
         <td align="right">40</td>
         <td align="right">45</td>
         <td align="right">50</td>
         <td align="right">55</td>
         <td align="right">60</td>
         <td align="right">65</td>
         <td align="right">70</td>
         <td align="right">75</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Blackberry</td>
         <td align="right">0.1</td>
         <td align="right">5</td>
         <td align="right">10</td>
         <td align="right">20</td>
         <td align="right">50</td>
         <td align="right">75</td>
         <td align="right">100</td>
         <td align="right">125</td>
         <td align="right">150</td>
         <td align="right">175</td>
         <td align="right">200</td>
         <td align="right">225</td>
         <td align="right">250</td>
         <td align="right">275</td>
         <td align="right">300</td>
         <td align="right">350</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Blackcurrant</td>
         <td align="right">0.1</td>
         <td align="right">0.5</td>
         <td align="right">1</td>
         <td align="right">2</td>
         <td align="right">2</td>
         <td align="right">4</td>
         <td align="right">4</td>
         <td align="right">4</td>
         <td align="right">6</td>
         <td align="right">6</td>
         <td align="right">6</td>
         <td align="right">8</td>
         <td align="right">8</td>
         <td align="right">10</td>
         <td align="right">12</td>
         <td align="right">14</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Blueberry</td>
         <td align="right">0.1</td>
         <td align="right">0.5</td>
         <td align="right">1</td>
         <td align="right">4</td>
         <td align="right">6</td>
         <td align="right">8</td>
         <td align="right">10</td>
         <td align="right">12</td>
         <td align="right">14</td>
         <td align="right">16</td>
         <td align="right">18</td>
         <td align="right">20</td>
         <td align="right">24</td>
         <td align="right">28</td>
         <td align="right">30</td>
         <td align="right">36</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Boysenberry</td>
         <td align="right">0.5</td>
         <td align="right">1</td>
         <td align="right">2.5</td>
         <td align="right">4</td>
         <td align="right">5.5</td>
         <td align="right">7</td>
         <td align="right">8.5</td>
         <td align="right">10</td>
         <td align="right">11.5</td>
         <td align="right">13</td>
         <td align="right">14.5</td>
         <td align="right">16</td>
         <td align="right">17.5</td>
         <td align="right">19</td>
         <td align="right">20.5</td>
         <td align="right">22</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Cherry</td>
         <td align="right">0.5</td>
         <td align="right">1</td>
         <td align="right">2.5</td>
         <td align="right">5</td>
         <td align="right">8</td>
         <td align="right">10</td>
         <td align="right">15</td>
         <td align="right">20</td>
         <td align="right">25</td>
         <td align="right">28</td>
         <td align="right">31</td>
         <td align="right">35</td>
         <td align="right">40</td>
         <td align="right">45</td>
         <td align="right">50</td>
         <td align="right">55</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Coconut</td>
         <td align="right">0.1</td>
         <td align="right">0.25</td>
         <td align="right">0.5</td>
         <td align="right">0.5</td>
         <td align="right">1</td>
         <td align="right">1</td>
         <td align="right">2</td>
         <td align="right">2</td>
         <td align="right">2</td>
         <td align="right">2</td>
         <td align="right">2.5</td>
         <td align="right">2.5</td>
         <td align="right">3</td>
         <td align="right">3</td>
         <td align="right">3</td>
         <td align="right">3</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you tried something?
With you've already tried it's easy to find the way.

Comment: I am a little confused can the user enter 233?  There is no text/number input in the sample.  I will echo the request for attempted javascript.

Comment: yes user can add any number to number fields then I will look up corresponding value from look up table, as it is change based on the two drop down.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
  $("input[type='text'].element").blur(function(e) {
  var result = $("<span name='result'>");
  var multiplier = $(`table#${$("#ProductOrigin").val()} tbody > tr[product='${$(this).attr("id")}'] > td[volume='${$("#Volume>option:selected").val()}']`).text();
  $(this).next("span").remove();
  result.text($(this).val() * multiplier);
  $(this).after(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <label class="description" for="ProductOrigin">Product Origin</label>
    <select class="element select medium" id="ProductOrigin" name="ProductOrigin">
        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="Europe">Europe</option>
        <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
        <option value="China">China</option>
        <option value="India">India</option>
        <option value="USA">USA</option>
        <option value="Africa">Africa</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <label class="description" for="Volume">Volume</label>
    <select class="element select medium" id="Volume" name="Volume">
        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="100">100</option>
        <option value="1000">1000</option>
        <option value="2000">2000</option>
        <option value="3000">3000</option>
        <option value="4000">4000</option>
        <option value="5000">5000</option>
        <option value="6000">6000</option>
        <option value="6000">6000</option>
        <option value="8000">8000</option>
        <option value="9000">9000</option>
        <option value="10000">10000</option>
        <option value="20000">20000</option>
        <option value="30000">30000</option>
        <option value="40000">40000</option>
        <option value="50000">50000</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <label class="description" for="Apple">Apple</label>
    <input id="Apple" name="Apple" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" />
</div>
<div>
    <label class="description" for="Apricot">Apricot</label>
    <input id="Apricot" name="Apricot" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" />
</div>
<div>
    <label class="description" for="Banana">Banana</label>
    <input id="Banana" name="Banana" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" />
</div>
<div>
    <label class="description" for="Bilberry">Bilberry</label>
    <input id="Bilberry" name="Bilberry" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" />
</div>
<div>
    <label class="description" for="Blackberry">Blackberry</label>
    <input id="Blackberry" name="Blackberry" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" />
</div>
<div>
    <label class="description" for="Blackcurrant">Blackcurrant</label>
    <input id="Blackcurrant" name="Blackcurrant" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" />
</div>
<div>
    <label class="description" for="Blueberry">Blueberry</label>
    <input id="Blueberry" name="Blueberry" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" />
</div>
<div>
    <label class="description" for="Boysenberry">Boysenberry</label>
    <input id="Boysenberry" name="Boysenberry" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" />
</div>
<div>
    <label class="description" for="Cherry">Cherry</label>
    <input id="Cherry" name="Cherry" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" />
</div>
<div>
    <label class="description" for="Coconut">Coconut</label>
    <input id="Coconut" name="Coconut" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" />
</div>


<table id="Europe">
    <thead>Europe</thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Europe</td>
            <th id=10>10</th>
            <th id=100>100</th>
            <th id=1000>1000</th>
            <th id=2000>2000</th>
            <th id=3000>3000</th>
            <th id=4000>4000</th>
            <th id=5000>5000</th>
            <th id=6000>6000</th>
            <th id=7000>7000</th>
            <th id=8000>8000</th>
            <th id=9000>9000</th>
            <th id=10000>10000</th>
            <th id=20000>20000</th>
            <th id=30000>30000</th>
            <th id=40000>40000</th>
            <th id=50000>50000</th>
        </tr>
    <tbody>
        <tr product='Apple'>
            <td>Apple</td>
            <td volume='10'>0.1</td>
            <td volume='100'>0.5</td>
            <td volume='1000'>1</td>
            <td volume='2000'>2</td>
            <td volume='3000'>3</td>
            <td volume='4000'>4</td>
            <td volume='5000'>5</td>
            <td volume='6000'>6</td>
            <td volume='7000'>7</td>
            <td volume='8000'>8</td>
            <td volume='9000'>9</td>
            <td volume='10000'>10</td>
            <td volume='20000'>11</td>
            <td volume='30000'>12</td>
            <td volume='40000'>13</td>
            <td volume='50000'>14</td>
        </tr>
        <tr product='Apricot'>
                <td>Apricot</td>
                <td volume='10'>0</td>
                <td volume='100'>0</td>
                <td volume='1000'>0</td>
                <td volume='2000'>0.5</td>
                <td volume='3000'>1</td>
                <td volume='4000'>1.5</td>
                <td volume='5000'>2</td>
                <td volume='6000'>2.5</td>
                <td volume='7000'>3</td>
                <td volume='8000'>3.5</td>
                <td volume='9000'>4</td>
                <td volume='10000'>4.5</td>
                <td volume='20000'>5</td>
                <td volume='30000'>5.5</td>
                <td volume='40000'>6</td>
                <td volume='50000'>7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr product='Banana'>
                <td>Banana</td>
                <td volume='10'>0.1</td>
                <td volume='100'>0.5</td>
                <td volume='1000'>1</td>
                <td volume='2000'>5</td>
                <td volume='3000'>10</td>
                <td volume='4000'>15</td>
                <td volume='5000'>20</td>
                <td volume='6000'>25</td>
                <td volume='7000'>27</td>
                <td volume='8000'>30</td>
                <td volume='9000'>33</td>
                <td volume='10000'>36</td>
                <td volume='20000'>40</td>
                <td volume='30000'>45</td>
                <td volume='40000'>50</td>
                <td volume='50000'>55</td>
              </tr>
              <tr product='Bilberry'>
                <td>Bilberry</td>
                <td volume='10'>1</td>
                <td volume='100'>5</td>
                <td volume='1000'>10</td>
                <td volume='2000'>15</td>
                <td volume='3000'>20</td>
                <td volume='4000'>25</td>
                <td volume='5000'>30</td>
                <td volume='6000'>35</td>
                <td volume='7000'>40</td>
                <td volume='8000'>45</td>
                <td volume='9000'>50</td>
                <td volume='10000'>55</td>
                <td volume='20000'>60</td>
                <td volume='30000'>65</td>
                <td volume='40000'>70</td>
                <td volume='50000'>75</td>
              </tr>
              <tr product='Blackberry'>
                <td>Blackberry</td>
                <td volume='10'>0.1</td>
                <td volume='100'>5</td>
                <td volume='1000'>10</td>
                <td volume='2000'>20</td>
                <td volume='3000'>50</td>
                <td volume='4000'>75</td>
                <td volume='5000'>100</td>
                <td volume='6000'>125</td>
                <td volume='7000'>150</td>
                <td volume='8000'>175</td>
                <td volume='9000'>200</td>
                <td volume='10000'>225</td>
                <td volume='20000'>250</td>
                <td volume='30000'>275</td>
                <td volume='40000'>300</td>
                <td volume='50000'>350</td>
              </tr>
              <tr product='Blackcurrant'>
                <td>Blackcurrant</td>
                <td volume='10'>0.1</td>
                <td volume='100'>0.5</td>
                <td volume='1000'>1</td>
                <td volume='2000'>2</td>
                <td volume='3000'>2</td>
                <td volume='4000'>4</td>
                <td volume='5000'>4</td>
                <td volume='6000'>4</td>
                <td volume='7000'>6</td>
                <td volume='8000'>6</td>
                <td volume='9000'>6</td>
                <td volume='10000'>8</td>
                <td volume='20000'>8</td>
                <td volume='30000'>10</td>
                <td volume='40000'>12</td>
                <td volume='50000'>14</td>
              </tr>
              <tr product='Blueberry'>
                <td>Blueberry</td>
                <td volume='10'>0.1</td>
                <td volume='100'>0.5</td>
                <td volume='1000'>1</td>
                <td volume='2000'>4</td>
                <td volume='3000'>6</td>
                <td volume='4000'>8</td>
                <td volume='5000'>10</td>
                <td volume='6000'>12</td>
                <td volume='7000'>14</td>
                <td volume='8000'>16</td>
                <td volume='9000'>18</td>
                <td volume='10000'>20</td>
                <td volume='20000'>24</td>
                <td volume='30000'>28</td>
                <td volume='40000'>30</td>
                <td volume='50000'>36</td>
              </tr>
              <tr product='Boysenberry'>
                <td>Boysenberry</td>
                <td volume='10'>0.5</td>
                <td volume='100'>1</td>
                <td volume='1000'>2.5</td>
                <td volume='2000'>4</td>
                <td volume='3000'>5.5</td>
                <td volume='4000'>7</td>
                <td volume='5000'>8.5</td>
                <td volume='6000'>10</td>
                <td volume='7000'>11.5</td>
                <td volume='8000'>13</td>
                <td volume='9000'>14.5</td>
                <td volume='10000'>16</td>
                <td volume='20000'>17.5</td>
                <td volume='30000'>19</td>
                <td volume='40000'>20.5</td>
                <td volume='50000'>22</td>
              </tr>
              <tr product='Cherry'>
                <td>Cherry</td>
                <td volume='10'>0.5</td>
                <td volume='100'>1</td>
                <td volume='1000'>2.5</td>
                <td volume='2000'>5</td>
                <td volume='3000'>8</td>
                <td volume='4000'>10</td>
                <td volume='5000'>15</td>
                <td volume='6000'>20</td>
                <td volume='7000'>25</td>
                <td volume='8000'>28</td>
                <td volume='9000'>31</td>
                <td volume='10000'>35</td>
                <td volume='20000'>40</td>
                <td volume='30000'>45</td>
                <td volume='40000'>50</td>
                <td volume='50000'>55</td>
              </tr>
              <tr product='Coconut'>
                <td>Coconut</td>
                <td volume='10'>0.1</td>
                <td volume='100'>0.25</td>
                <td volume='1000'>0.5</td>
                <td volume='2000'>0.5</td>
                <td volume='3000'>1</td>
                <td volume='4000'>1</td>
                <td volume='5000'>2</td>
                <td volume='6000'>2</td>
                <td volume='7000'>2</td>
                <td volume='8000'>2</td>
                <td volume='9000'>2.5</td>
                <td volume='10000'>2.5</td>
                <td volume='20000'>3</td>
                <td volume='30000'>3</td>
                <td volume='40000'>3</td>
                <td volume='50000'>3</td>
              </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Calculate dropdown matching Tables

This is working version.

Answer (score 0):

Your html makes your task far more difficult then it needs to be.  The fact that your `select` options do not directly relate to the table you need a value from is likely your main source of grief.  This answer leaves your HTML alone and works with it.  For a simpler solution I recommend;

1. Give your reference tables an ID, and make that ID the value of the origin select options.
2. Give your table cells an attribute that relates or is the value of the related volume select option.

*EXAMPLE* of HTML changes

```
<table id="origin_1">
   <thead>...Europe...<thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr product='apple'>...<td volume='1000'>0.5</td>...</tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

 $("input[type='text'].element").blur(function(e) {
  var result = $("<span name='result'>");
  var multiplier = $(`table#${$("#element_2").val()} tbody > tr[product='${$(this).attr("id")}'] > td[volume='${$("#element_1>option:selected").val()}']`).text();
  $(this).next("span").remove();
  result.text($(this).val() * multiplier);
  $(this).after(result);
});
```

*EXISTING HTML SNIPPET*

```js
$("input[type='text'].element").blur(function(e) {
  //get the origin
  var origin = $("#element_2>option:selected").text();
  //get the right lookup table (would be simpler if it had an ID with the value of the ORIGIN select)
  var $tblOrig = $($("table>thead>tr>th:first-child()>strong")
    .filter((index, elem) => $(elem).text().includes(origin)).closest("table"));
  //get the volume
  var volume = $("#element_1>option:selected").val();
  //calculate the targeted table row, we can use the ID for this
  var product_ord = $(this).attr("id").split("_")[1];
  //get the cell number that we need (would be easier of the value of the volume option was the index)
  var volume_ord =
    $("#element_1>option").map((i, e) => {
      return e.value == volume ? {
        index: i + 1
      } : null;
    })[0].index;
  //console.log(volume_ord);

  //get the multiplier
  //make somewhere to store the answer
  var result = $("<span name='result'>");
  //get the value from the right cell
  var multiplier = $tblOrig
    .find(`tbody > tr:nth-child(${product_ord}) > td:nth-child(${volume_ord})`).text();
  //console.log(multiplier);
  //remove a previous answer if there is one
  $(this).next("span").remove();
  //get the new answer
  result.text($(this).val() * multiplier);
  //put it after the text input
  $(this).after(result);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label class="description" for="element_2">Product Origin</label>
  <select class="element select medium" id="element_2" name="element_2">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="1">Europe</option>
    <option value="2">Asia</option>
    <option value="3">China</option>
    <option value="3">India</option>
    <option value="3">USA</option>
    <option value="3">Africa</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <label class="description" for="element_1">Volume</label>
  <select class="element select medium" id="element_1" name="element_1">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
    <option value="1000">1000</option>
    <option value="2000">2000</option>
    <option value="3000">3000</option>
    <option value="4000">4000</option>
    <option value="5000">5000</option>
    <option value="6000">6000</option>
    <option value="6000">6000</option>
    <option value="8000">8000</option>
    <option value="9000">9000</option>
    <option value="10000">10000</option>
    <option value="20000">20000</option>
    <option value="30000">30000</option>
    <option value="40000">40000</option>
    <option value="50000">50000</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <label class="description" for="element_1">Apple </label>
  <input id="element_1" name="element_1" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" />
</div>
<div>
  <label class="description" for="element_2">Apricot </label>
  <input id="element_2" name="element_2" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" />
</div>
<div>
  <label class="description" for="element_3">Banana </label>
  <input id="element_3" name="element_3" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" />
</div>
<div>
  <label class="description" for="element_4">Bilberry </label>
  <input id="element_4" name="element_4" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" />
</div>
<div>
  <label class="description" for="element_5">Blackberry </label>
  <input id="element_5" name="element_5" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" />
</div>
<div>
  <label class="description" for="element_6">Blackcurrant </label>
  <input id="element_6" name="element_6" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" />
</div>
<div>
  <label class="description" for="element_7">Blueberry </label>
  <input id="element_7" name="element_7" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" />
</div>
<div>
  <label class="description" for="element_8">Boysenberry </label>
  <input id="element_8" name="element_8" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" />
</div>
<div>
  <label class="description" for="element_9">Cherry </label>
  <input id="element_9" name="element_9" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" />
</div>
<div>
  <label class="description" for="element_10">Coconut </label>
  <input id="element_10" name="element_10" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" />
</div>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th title="Field #1"><strong>Category 1: Origin Europe</strong></th>
      <th title="Field #2"><strong>10</strong></th>
      <th title="Field #3"><strong>100</strong></th>
      <th title="Field #4"><strong>1000</strong></th>
      <th title="Field #5"><strong>2000</strong></th>
      <th title="Field #6"><strong>3000</strong></th>
      <th title="Field #7"><strong>4000</strong></th>
      <th title="Field #8"><strong>5000</strong></th>
      <th title="Field #9"><strong>6000</strong></th>
      <th title="Field #10"><strong>7000</strong></th>
      <th title="Field #11"><strong>8000</strong></th>
      <th title="Field #12"><strong>9000</strong></th>
      <th title="Field #13"><strong>1000</strong></th>
      <th title="Field #14"><strong>10000</strong></th>
      <th title="Field #15"><strong>20000</strong></th>
      <th title="Field #16"><strong>30000</strong></th>
      <th title="Field #17"><strong>40000</strong></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td align="right">0.1</td>
      <td align="right">0.5</td>
      <td align="right">1</td>
      <td align="right">2</td>
      <td align="right">3</td>
      <td align="right">4</td>
      <td align="right">5</td>
      <td align="right">6</td>
      <td align="right">7</td>
      <td align="right">8</td>
      <td align="right">9</td>
      <td align="right">10</td>
      <td align="right">11</td>
      <td align="right">12</td>
      <td align="right">13</td>
      <td align="right">14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Apricot</td>
      <td align="right">0</td>
      <td align="right">0</td>
      <td align="right">0</td>
      <td align="right">0.5</td>
      <td align="right">1</td>
      <td align="right">1.5</td>
      <td align="right">2</td>
      <td align="right">2.5</td>
      <td align="right">3</td>
      <td align="right">3.5</td>
      <td align="right">4</td>
      <td align="right">4.5</td>
      <td align="right">5</td>
      <td align="right">5.5</td>
      <td align="right">6</td>
      <td align="right">7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Banana</td>
      <td align="right">0.1</td>
      <td align="right">0.5</td>
      <td align="right">1</td>
      <td align="right">2</td>
      <td align="right">4</td>
      <td align="right">5</td>
      <td align="right">6</td>
      <td align="right">7</td>
      <td align="right">8</td>
      <td align="right">9</td>
      <td align="right">10</td>
      <td align="right">12</td>
      <td align="right">14</td>
      <td align="right">16</td>
      <td align="right">18</td>
      <td align="right">20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bilberry</td>
      <td align="right">1</td>
      <td align="right">5</td>
      <td align="right">10</td>
      <td align="right">10</td>
      <td align="right">15</td>
      <td align="right">20</td>
      <td align="right">25</td>
      <td align="right">30</td>
      <td align="right">35</td>
      <td align="right">40</td>
      <td align="right">45</td>
      <td align="right">50</td>
      <td align="right">55</td>
      <td align="right">60</td>
      <td align="right">65</td>
      <td align="right">70</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Blackberry</td>
      <td align="right">0.1</td>
      <td align="right">5</td>
      <td align="right">10</td>
      <td align="right">20</td>
      <td align="right">50</td>
      <td align="right">75</td>
      <td align="right">100</td>
      <td align="right">125</td>
      <td align="right">150</td>
      <td align="right">175</td>
      <td align="right">200</td>
      <td align="right">225</td>
      <td align="right">250</td>
      <td align="right">275</td>
      <td align="right">300</td>
      <td align="right">350</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Blackcurrant</td>
      <td align="right">0.1</td>
      <td align="right">0.5</td>
      <td align="right">1</td>
      <td align="right">2</td>
      <td align="right">2</td>
      <td align="right">4</td>
      <td align="right">4</td>
      <td align="right">4</td>
      <td align="right">6</td>
      <td align="right">6</td>
      <td align="right">6</td>
      <td align="right">8</td>
      <td align="right">8</td>
      <td align="right">10</td>
      <td align="right">12</td>
      <td align="right">14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Blueberry</td>
      <td align="right">0.1</td>
      <td align="right">0.5</td>
      <td align="right">1</td>
      <td align="right">4</td>
      <td align="right">6</td>
      <td align="right">8</td>
      <td align="right">10</td>
      <td align="right">12</td>
      <td align="right">14</td>
      <td align="right">16</td>
      <td align="right">18</td>
      <td align="right">20</td>
      <td align="right">24</td>
      <td align="right">28</td>
      <td align="right">30</td>
      <td align="right">36</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Boysenberry</td>
      <td align="right">0.5</td>
      <td align="right">1</td>
      <td align="right">2.5</td>
      <td align="right">4</td>
      <td align="right">5.5</td>
      <td align="right">7</td>
      <td align="right">8.5</td>
      <td align="right">10</td>
      <td align="right">11.5</td>
      <td align="right">13</td>
      <td align="right">14.5</td>
      <td align="right">16</td>
      <td align="right">17.5</td>
      <td align="right">19</td>
      <td align="right">20.5</td>
      <td align="right">22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cherry</td>
      <td align="right">0.5</td>
      <td align="right">1</td>
      <td align="right">2.5</td>
      <td align="right">5</td>
      <td align="right">8</td>
      <td align="right">10</td>
      <td align="right">15</td>
      <td align="right">20</td>
      <td align="right">25</td>
      <td align="right">28</td>
      <td align="right">31</td>
      <td align="right">35</td>
      <td align="right">40</td>
      <td align="right">45</td>
      <td align="right">50</td>
      <td align="right">55</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Coconut</td>
      <td align="right">0.1</td>
      <td align="right">0.25</td>
      <td align="right">0.5</td>
      <td align="right">0.5</td>
      <td align="right">1</td>
      <td align="right">1</td>
      <td align="right">2</td>
      <td align="right">2</td>
      <td align="right">2</td>
      <td align="right">2</td>
      <td align="right">2.5</td>
      <td align="right">2.5</td>
      <td align="right">3</td>
      <td align="right">3</td>
      <td align="right">3</td>
      <td align="right">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      </br>
      </br>
      <td><strong>Category 2 Origin Asia</strong></td>
      <td align="right"><strong>10</strong></td>
      <td align="right"><strong>100</strong></td>
      <td align="right"><strong>1000</strong></td>
      <td align="right"><strong>2000</strong></td>
      <td align="right"><strong>3000</strong></td>
      <td align="right"><strong>4000</strong></td>
      <td align="right"><strong>5000</strong></td>
      <td align="right"><strong>6000</strong></td>
      <td align="right"><strong>7000</strong></td>
      <td align="right"><strong>8000</strong></td>
      <td align="right"><strong>9000</strong></td>
      <td align="right"><strong>1000</strong></td>
      <td align="right"><strong>10000</strong></td>
      <td align="right"><strong>20000</strong></td>
      <td align="right"><strong>30000</strong></td>
      <td align="right"><strong>40000</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td align="right">0.1</td>
      <td align="right">0.5</td>
      <td align="right">1</td>
      <td align="right">5</td>
      <td align="right">10</td>
      <td align="right">15</td>
      <td align="right">17.7</td>
      <td align="right">21.5</td>
      <td align="right">25.3</td>
      <td align="right">29.1</td>
      <td align="right">32.9</td>
      <td align="right">36.7</td>
      <td align="right">40.5</td>
      <td align="right">44.3</td>
      <td align="right">48.1</td>
      <td align="right">51.9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Apricot</td>
      <td align="right">0</td>
      <td align="right">0</td>
      <td align="right">0</td>
      <td align="right">0.5</td>
      <td align="right">1</td>
      <td align="right">1.5</td>
      <td align="right">2</td>
      <td align="right">2.5</td>
      <td align="right">3</td>
      <td align="right">3.5</td>
      <td align="right">4</td>
      <td align="right">4.5</td>
      <td align="right">5</td>
      <td align="right">5.5</td>
      <td align="right">6</td>
      <td align="right">7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Banana</td>
      <td align="right">0.1</td>
      <td align="right">0.5</td>
      <td align="right">1</td>
      <td align="right">5</td>
      <td align="right">10</td>
      <td align="right">15</td>
      <td align="right">20</td>
      <td align="right">25</td>
      <td align="right">27</td>
      <td align="right">30</td>
      <td align="right">33</td>
      <td align="right">36</td>
      <td align="right">40</td>
      <td align="right">45</td>
      <td align="right">50</td>
      <td align="right">55</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bilberry</td>
      <td align="right">1</td>
      <td align="right">5</td>
      <td align="right">10</td>
      <td align="right">15</td>
      <td align="right">20</td>
      <td align="right">25</td>
      <td align="right">30</td>
      <td align="right">35</td>
      <td align="right">40</td>
      <td align="right">45</td>
      <td align="right">50</td>
      <td align="right">55</td>
      <td align="right">60</td>
      <td align="right">65</td>
      <td align="right">70</td>
      <td align="right">75</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Blackberry</td>
      <td align="right">0.1</td>
      <td align="right">5</td>
      <td align="right">10</td>
      <td align="right">20</td>
      <td align="right">50</td>
      <td align="right">75</td>
      <td align="right">100</td>
      <td align="right">125</td>
      <td align="right">150</td>
      <td align="right">175</td>
      <td align="right">200</td>
      <td align="right">225</td>
      <td align="right">250</td>
      <td align="right">275</td>
      <td align="right">300</td>
      <td align="right">350</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Blackcurrant</td>
      <td align="right">0.1</td>
      <td align="right">0.5</td>
      <td align="right">1</td>
      <td align="right">2</td>
      <td align="right">2</td>
      <td align="right">4</td>
      <td align="right">4</td>
      <td align="right">4</td>
      <td align="right">6</td>
      <td align="right">6</td>
      <td align="right">6</td>
      <td align="right">8</td>
      <td align="right">8</td>
      <td align="right">10</td>
      <td align="right">12</td>
      <td align="right">14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Blueberry</td>
      <td align="right">0.1</td>
      <td align="right">0.5</td>
      <td align="right">1</td>
      <td align="right">4</td>
      <td align="right">6</td>
      <td align="right">8</td>
      <td align="right">10</td>
      <td align="right">12</td>
      <td align="right">14</td>
      <td align="right">16</td>
      <td align="right">18</td>
      <td align="right">20</td>
      <td align="right">24</td>
      <td align="right">28</td>
      <td align="right">30</td>
      <td align="right">36</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Boysenberry</td>
      <td align="right">0.5</td>
      <td align="right">1</td>
      <td align="right">2.5</td>
      <td align="right">4</td>
      <td align="right">5.5</td>
      <td align="right">7</td>
      <td align="right">8.5</td>
      <td align="right">10</td>
      <td align="right">11.5</td>
      <td align="right">13</td>
      <td align="right">14.5</td>
      <td align="right">16</td>
      <td align="right">17.5</td>
      <td align="right">19</td>
      <td align="right">20.5</td>
      <td align="right">22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cherry</td>
      <td align="right">0.5</td>
      <td align="right">1</td>
      <td align="right">2.5</td>
      <td align="right">5</td>
      <td align="right">8</td>
      <td align="right">10</td>
      <td align="right">15</td>
      <td align="right">20</td>
      <td align="right">25</td>
      <td align="right">28</td>
      <td align="right">31</td>
      <td align="right">35</td>
      <td align="right">40</td>
      <td align="right">45</td>
      <td align="right">50</td>
      <td align="right">55</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Coconut</td>
      <td align="right">0.1</td>
      <td align="right">0.25</td>
      <td align="right">0.5</td>
      <td align="right">0.5</td>
      <td align="right">1</td>
      <td align="right">1</td>
      <td align="right">2</td>
      <td align="right">2</td>
      <td align="right">2</td>
      <td align="right">2</td>
      <td align="right">2.5</td>
      <td align="right">2.5</td>
      <td align="right">3</td>
      <td align="right">3</td>
      <td align="right">3</td>
      <td align="right">3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: many thanks Steve, I will follow your guidance and try it out.